# find and kill all docker instances older than 1 day

Tags: linux, docker

I need to run a command

```
 docker ps -a
```

which says lists:

```
id    name   time
1      abc    6 weeks ago
```

To kill we need to fire the command:

```
docker kill id
```

I need to find all ids and run the kill command on each id which is older than 1 day. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11):

Some docker commands provide the possibility to adjust the output format using go template. Thus, we can use that mechanism to get the start time of the running containers that is easier to process.

For example:

```
docker ps --format='{{.ID}}' \
  | xargs -n 1 -r docker inspect \
                           -f '{{.ID}} {{.State.Running}} {{.State.StartedAt}}' \
  | awk '$2 == "true" && $3 <= "'$(date -d 'yesterday' -Ins --utc \
                                     | sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" { print $1 }' \
  | xargs -r docker kill
```

We assume GNU `xargs` here - the `-r` option instruct `xargs` to only execute the command if there is at least one argument. We also rely on GNU `date` - the objective is to get yesterdays date+time - in ISO format with Zulu time suffix - such that it is compatible with the internal docker date format. Thus, both dates can be compared using normal string comparison, because the lexcicographic ordering of that date format matches the date ordering.

The `ps` docker command doesn't have the `-a` option set because by default, `docker ps` only shows the running containers - and we only need to look at the running ones for killing.

If you have an docker command alias defined (e.g. `alias docker='sudo /usr/bin/docker'`) you have to replace `docker` with `sudo /usr/bin/docker` in that pipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was searching for! I've injected the code into this [script](https://gist.github.com/weshouman/f0398fcfb14a3d0e7c59a92cf3a3db52) to easily search by age

Comment: If your timezone is not set to UTC, you need to remove the `--utc` flag from `date` or this won't work.